# javascript calling object

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I'm kind of new to this so a bit confused.

I have a js file named rrr.js, in which I have this code:

```
var rrr_rrr2=
{
    // get the domain name from the current url
    get_domain_name:function()
    {
        //code here...
    },
// other functions here
}
```

Now in my HTML page I simply added it like I usually do:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="rrr.js">
```

and called it like this:

```
Step 1 completed!<br><br>Click <a href="javascript:rrr_rrr2.get_domain_name()">here</a>
```

But that does not work... what am I doing wrong?

(by the way, this is in a firefox addon. FF gives me this error:

```
Error: rrr_rrr2 is not defined
Source File: javascript:rrr_rrr2.get_domain_name()
Line: 1
```

Help please!

Comment: Is the resource `rrr.js` loaded correctly? (Use Firebug or similar) Does the global property `rrr_rrr2` contain the value expected from a debugger/console? (Use Firebug or similar) -- and a pet-peeve: *do not use `var` for global properties* -- it will work, but does not mean the same as `var` in a function context. Best just to leave it out. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Satyajit was almost right. Try closing it like this instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="rrr.js"></script>
```

But also, if this js file is part of your addon, you can't access it directly from an HTML page, unless you put it at a `resource:` URI or something. Read up on privileged vs. unprivileged code.

Comment: I fool stupid... I forgot the closing script tag like you wrote above (after years of using it) thanks! (*Slinks away with egg on face!)

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you have not closed the  tag like so

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="rrr.js"**/**>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothin is wrong with the code you have just shown, I have reproduced it in this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Dxs9/2/).

There is one thing to look out for: the variable `rrr_rrr2` must be in the global scope to access it with the `javascript:` href. If it is defined inside of a function, for example, then it is not in the global scope and cannot be accessed.

Comment: Forgot to close the tag, all I needed to do was add a </script> :(